# Adobe Flex простой запрос HTTP GET

Tags: http, flash, actionscript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Ищу самый простой способ получить код страницы(в моем случае это XML файл) в Flex/AS3.
интересует самый простой способ, можно используя библиотеки.
кроме того нужен именно синхронный способ(не асинхронный).
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В AS3/Flex нет синхронного способа получить ответ на HTTP запрос.

Именно во Flex можно например получить так: (Flex 4 и выше)

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="myXML" source="http://server.org/xml/test.xml" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

Для чистого AS3:

```
private function requestXML():void {
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handler);
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("source.xml"));
}

private function handler(e:Event):void {
    var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
}
```

Не забудьте подписаться на события ошибок.

Вот еще способ получить ХМЛ во флекс:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="xmlDataLoader" url="http://server.com/xml/data.xml"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:List id="targetList" dataProvider="{xmlDataLoader.lastResult.document.item}" labelField="fieldName" creationComplete="{xmlDataLoader.send()}"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
может еще знаете, как из assets загрузить XML?

Comment: Что такое assets?